# General solution for $y^{iv}+ 2y''+y=\cos x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Here is another problem from Mathews and Walker that has given me some trouble.

> **1-18**. Find the general solution of
>   $y^{iv}+ 2y''+y=\cos x$.

*Note: Thanks, everyone, for clearing up the interpretation of $y^{iv}$ as the fourth derivative of $y$ and for the clear solutions. 
I had interpreted $y^{iv}$ as $y^{\sqrt{-1} \ v}$ with $v\in \mathbb{C}$. 
Of course, this is an awful nonlinear DE!*

Comment: I would try something of the type $f(x)=P(x) \cos(x)$ where $P$ is a fourth degree polynomial...

Comment: That first term is the 4th derivative of y?  Would this make things easier for you?  If $z=y''+y$, the left side reduces to $z''+z$

Comment: Surely it is the fourth derivative, although perhaps M & W were not consistent in using it.

Comment: @oenamen: Generally, with a *number* you are correct that $y^k$ means the $k$th power and $y^{(k)}$ the $k$th derivative; so $y^4$ would mean the $4$th power, and $y^{(4)}$ the fourth derivative. However, when *roman numerals* are used in the exponent, the meaning, in my experience, is *never* the power! If you really wanted the fourth power, it would be written $y^4$, not $y^{iv}$. Roman numerals are often used for the derivative, so that the $4$th derivative could be written *either* $y^{(4)}$ or as $y^{iv}$; *never* as $y^{(iv)}$ or as $y^4$. The fourth power would be $y^4$, not $y^{iv}$

Comment: @oenamen: Do you think that is a reasonable, or unreasonable, interpretation?

Comment: @onamen: Sorry, but that is just unreasonable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look closely to your ODE's LH side, you discover that:
$$y^{(IV)}+2y^{\prime \prime}+y= (y^{\prime \prime} +y)^{\prime \prime} +(y^{\prime \prime}+y)\; .$$
After the substitution $u=y^{\prime \prime} +y$, your ODE rewrites:
$$u^{\prime \prime} +u =\cos x\; ,$$
which is a simple second order linear equation and thus can be solved explicitly with ease; in particular, after some computations, you find:
$$u(x)=A\ \cos x+ B\ \sin x + \frac{1}{2}\ x\ \sin x\; .$$
Now you can return to the original unknown $y$: the only thing you have to do is to solve the ODE:
$$\tag{1} y^{\prime \prime} + y = A\ \cos x+ B\ \sin x + \frac{1}{2}\ x\ \sin x$$
which is again a simple second order linear equation. In order to solve the latter ODE in a clever way, you can observe that $y$ solve (**1**) iff $y(x)=\bar{y}(x) + y_1(x) + y_2(x) + y_3(x)$ where $\bar{y}$ is the general solution of $\bar{y}^{\prime \prime} + \bar{y} =0$ (which will depend on two arbitrary constants $C,D\in \mathbb{R}$) and $y_1,\ y_2,\ y_3$ are particular solutions of:
$$y_1^{\prime \prime} +y_1 = A\cos x,\qquad y_2^{\prime \prime} +y_2=B\sin x ,\qquad y_3^{\prime \prime} + y_3=\frac{1}{2}x\sin x\; .$$

Answer (score 2):

You did not try the easiest way. It is a linear equation with constant coefficients. The characteristic equation is
$$
r^4+2\,r^2+1=(r^2+1)^2=0\implies r=\pm i,\text{ roots of multiplicity $2$.}
$$
The solution of the homogeneous equation is
$$
y_h=C_1\cos x+C_2\sin x+C_3x\cos x+C_4x\sin x.
$$
Lookig at the right hans side, we know that there is a particular solution of the complete equation of the form
$$
y_p=x^2(A\cos x+B\sin x).
$$
$A$ and $B$ are found substituting $y_p$ in the equation. Its general solution is
$$
y=y_h+y_p.
$$